# If you have two functions of the same name (overloaded), and there is a conversion constructor, will the conversion constuctor be called?

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, overload-resolution

Suppose that you overload a function:

```
void display_widget( float f );    
void display_widget( Apple a );
```

My question is, which has higher precedence:

1. a conversion constructor constructing an `Apple` from a `float`
2. The overloaded function having `float` in its parameter list

```
    #include <iostream>    
    class Apple
    {
        public:
            Apple() : f{ 0.0 } {};
            float get_f() { return f; }

            Apple(float _f) : f{ _f } {};
            operator float()  { return f; }

        private:
            float f;
    };    

    void display_widget( float f )
    {
        std::cout << "The float is: " << f << std::endl;
    }    

    void display_widget( Apple a ) 
    {
        std::cout << "The Apple is: " << a.get_f() << std::endl;
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {      
        display_widget(49.95);        
        return 0;
    }
```

Note that we have two `display_widget` functions, one accepting an `Apple` and the other accepting a `float`

Consider the following line inside of `main`:

```
display_widget(49.95);
```

Which of the following is the correct pseudo-code describing what happens:

```
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|            option 1             |            option 2            |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| display_widget( float f );      | a = Apple( float _f );         |
|                                 | display_widget( Apple a );     |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

`display_widget( float f )` will be selected.

Given `display_widget(49.95);`, for `display_widget(float)` to be called, the implicit conversion sequence contains only one standard conversion (from `double` to `float`). For `display_widget(Apple)` to be called, the conversion sequence contains one standard conversion (from `double` to `float`) and one user-defined conversion (from `float` to `Apple`), and then is qualified as user-defined conversion sequence. The standard conversion sequence has higher ranking in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences).

> A standard conversion sequence is always better than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence.

Comment: That, and during overload resolution, only 1 implicit conversion is allowed. Since `49.95` is a `double`, there is only 1 overload that would invoke 1 implicit conversion, the other overload invokes 2 implicit conversions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Only 1 user-defined implicit conversion is allowed. Multiple standard conversions or multiple standard conversions + 1 user-defined conversion would be fine.